# Paypal IP Recurring Subscriptions - custom field

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a Paypal IPN script for notifications.

When creating subcriptions through Paypal, is the 'custom' field returned with each IPN response? eg. when a recurring payment is made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Once you verify the IPN, (well actually before as well but always verify first...) the name value pair collection you get will contain all fields that have data, including the "custom" field.

For reference this shows all possible values in a subscriptin IPN

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside